# Extracting data from series of excel files

Tags: excel, time-series

I have a series of Excel data with multiple cities and sensors in a single worksheet. What would be the fastest and most accurate way to extract data from a city X and a Y sensor?

In my case, I need only the data from the sensor "umidade_solo_nivel1".

I could do with pivot table, but it would take a lot of time, since there are 66 cities and a different Excel worksheet for each month of the year.

Following is an image of the worksheet that helps you understand how the data is organized.

[image: [1]]

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide.

Comment: There are multiple ways to handle this.  You can use a macro with VBA, pivot tables like you said, use a script like C# to read and compile them all together, you could use a series of offsets and counters. I am sure their are even more ways to handle this.  Unfortunately I cannot think of a solution where you wont have to reference each sheet.  This is the problem of using Excel as a "database" and not storing this information in a centralized location with properly structured tables.  I would recommend you just use pivot tables.

Comment: To David's suggestion, I would add MS Access. As I understand it you want to essentially combine your sheets into one table. It's easy to import Excel into Access. If you want to do this regularly and not as a one-off process I'd definitely look at VBA though.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to set up your file to include "indicators" and the =INDIRECT() function.  Using this, you can set up a series of indicators (in separate rows) which include the sheet name, row, and column of data you are looking for.  This can be somewhat time-intensive to set up at first, but can definitely pay off in the long run, especially if your data are periodically updated or if more data is entered.  All it takes is a little creativity.

If you are not familiar with the function, you could check out this website:
http://www.contextures.com/xlFunctions05.html

As David Lee mentioned in your comments, VBA or other languages like Python or C# could also be of use.  As we can not fully understand what you need specifically or what all of your data look like from your description, I would recommend learning the function I mentioned and evaluating if it would be helpful in this context before learning another language like VBA (though I highly recommend learning VBA if you anticipate spending lots of time in Excel).